# Cookie SameSite attribute

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

In a spring boot application who use thymeleaf.

When user select item in a selection, i set a value in a cookie to be able to come back

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
     <form>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="testType" th:text="#{testTypeEnum.select.label}"></label>
             <select class="form-control" id="testType" >
                 <option th:value="NULL" selected="selected" th:text="#{form.select.empty}"></option>
                  <option th:each="testType : ${testTypes}" th:value="${testType}" th:text="#{'testTypeEnum.'+${testType}}"></option>
             </select>
         </div>
     </form>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $("#testType").on('change', function() {
            var valueSelected=  this.value;
                
            document.cookie = "selectedTestType="+valueSelected;

             var url = "/samplestesttable?testTypeValue="+valueSelected;
             $("#testListResultFragment").load(url);
             
        });

      function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }
        }
        return "";
    }


   var selectedTestType = getCookie("selectedTestType");
   if(selectedTestType !== ""){
       $("#testType").val(selectedTestType).change();
    }
 });
</script>
```

That work well.

But since a few month, in the browser dev console I see

> Cookie “selectedTestType” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value

Maybe is there a better way to do the same thing now?